# How to delete secrets older than 24 hours using kubectl?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have the following command:

```
kubectl delete -n vnamespace secret --field-selector type=my_secret
```

this works fine but delete all secrets. I want to delete secrets older than 24 hours. How can I add it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `jq` to parse kubectl output and list all secrets older than 24h, and pass it to delete.

```sh
kubectl delete secret -n vnamespace $(kubectl -n vnamespace get secrets --field-selector type=my_secret -o json | jq -r "[.items[] | {name: .metadata.name, startTime: .metadata.creationTimestamp | fromdate } | select(.startTime < (now | . - 86400))]" | jq -r ".[].name")
```

Comment: Something is missing here this will delete all secrets.. where is the --field-selector type=my_secret comes in?

Comment: Add `--field-selector type=my_secret` after `kubectl -n vnamespace get secrets`. @Cloudziu could you please update your answer to include `--field-selector`?